# Toggle two side button css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, button, radio-button

I create a css button with some tutorial jsfiddle.net/EC2Eh/12/  but this is based on 
jquery mobile. How to create a similar button just with javascript that will work like that button, and also where I can change a color of button and dimension.

Here on this jsfiddle.net/EC2Eh/12/ I can't change any color, dimension and so. So can you please tell me is there some tutotial to build this button bar (radio button) that will work just like that but where I can change all things.

Thanksa lot!
and sorry abut my english is not very well but I;m leasen hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just 3 steps you have to follow:

1. take 2 divs
2. adjust height ,width
3. give the divs rounded border
4. change color on MouseHover event and onClick event

Comment: is there some like that on jsfidle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sourcecode/L3hgA/ try this , i've made it only for demo , this is just a very easy example, just include more and more feature it'll on its own translate into more live format...:)

Comment: i need when i click on div to stay colored and other to off... this something like on/off ... so if sme this on clicked change color, other cant

Comment: try your hands over this tutorial- http://api.jquery.com/?s=mouse , you'll surely get your answer ..and knowledge too ...

Answer (score 0):

Download firebug for firefox, right click on the element in the fiddle  and copy out all the css for that element and apply it to your button.

Comment: ok, I do that, and when i create this: http://jsfiddle.net/heZBT/ but how to change css to space beetween buttons be 0px;